# I don't understand why Gmail doesn't show 'to' value when I get mail via smtplib

Tags: python, gmail, smtplib

```
def send_me_mail(email_message: str):
    with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.office365.com", port=587) as connection:
        connection.starttls()
        connection.login(MAIL_ID, PASSWORD)
        connection.sendmail(
            from_addr=MAIL_ID,
            to_addrs="GMAIL_ID",
            msg=email_message
        )

send_me_mail("Subject: New Message\n\nYou have got a mail!!")
```

I receive this mail perfectly. But usually in Gmail, in '`to`' it says *You* and clicking on you gives you your gamil id. But there was nothing in '`to`'.
Is this Gmail quirk or I am missing something?

I tried changing the `to_addrs` values to outlook mail. Even there, there was no value for `to`.
I checked by sending mails directly from account, then it shows `to` values in both Gmail and Outlook.

04-March-2023: After the comment from Barmar I tried using `send_message()` method using `EmailMessage()` object, where there are headers, and it worked. Thanks Barmar for the idea.

***But the question remains, anyway to do that using `sendmail()` method?***

Comment: Read the documentation: ***Note** The from_addr and to_addrs parameters are used to construct the message envelope used by the transport agents. sendmail does not modify the message headers in any way.*

Comment: So you need to add a `To:` header.